# How to use "sideMenu" and "bottomTabs" parameters nested?

Tags: wix-react-native-navigation

I decided to switch from `@react-navigation/*` to `react-native-navigation`, but I'm having trouble applying the previous application structure to `react-native-navigation`.

In the old build some stacks used specific views (Drawer, BottomTabs etc), in `react-native-navigation` it's like there is a single `sideMenu` and `bottomTabs` wrapped in the main component, how can I use different drawer menus on different screens or groups of screens.

[Old `NavigationContainer` content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PobRj.png)

Thank you in advance for your feedback.